# Starting VLC via command line to play a video as desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows-8, command-line, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to create a batch script to start a video as a live wallpaper on startup. Right-clicking a playing video and selecting the "Set as wallpaper" option works fine, but attempting to run VLC with the following flags fails and only renders the video in the top left corner of the screen:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller --qt-start-minimized --qt-system-tray --video-wallpaper "D:\carrey.mpg"
```

Is this a bug in VLC or am I not formatting the command correctly? I've tried a few different versions of the command script, but the same thing happens each time. I'm on Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set any size so maybe VLC media player will play the movie in its original size/resolution.

I think adding the size to your command will solve your problem.

`--width, --height <integer>` sets the video window dimensions. By default, the video window size will be adjusted to match the video dimensions.

Source: *[Advanced Use of VLC, Video options](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Advanced_Use_of_VLC#Video_options)*

Comment: I noticed when setting the resolution's to my screen resolution or full screen there's a black flash the size of the screen, but the video still shows at it's original resolution. Adding width and height flags didn't help.

Comment: Ok, good to know, i thought this should work. I don't had the time to read through it but maybe the vlc forum may help you: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=100222

Comment: I already went through the forums and tried all the solutions there; trying the commands on those posts resulted in my desktop having a pink screen instead of video at best.